# How do I remove pychram in pop os

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

I install pychram to my Pop Os, but some case my pycharm is not work, becouse I want to completly remove pychrm.  Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Next time use google.
I found that using Pop!_Os you can run this command to uninstall pycharm:

```
sudo apt remove pycharm
```

...or you can follow this guide:
https://vitux.com/how-to-uninstall-programs-from-your-ubuntu-system/

Comment: I normally use firefox. this reply most helpful to me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pop OS is debian based .. so you can use this command to uninstall any package you no longer want ---> `sudo apt remove "package name"` .. and if you're not sure what the package name is, you can find it easily with a google search .. so you can use `sudo apt remove pycharm`